# cv2.imwrite doesn't save result image but initial only

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a code:

```
import cv2
import numpy

background = numpy.zeros((1080, 1920, 3))
img = numpy.ones((255, 465, 3))
offset = numpy.array((12, 12))

x_offset = offset[0]
y_offset = offset[1]

img_w = img.shape[1]
img_h = img.shape[0]

background_w = background.shape[1]
background_h = background.shape[0]

x = x_offset
y = y_offset
for i in range(0, 16):
    background[y:y + img.shape[0], x:x + img.shape[1]] = img
    x += img_w + x_offset
    if x > background_w - img_w:
        x = x_offset
        y += img_h + y_offset

cv2.imshow("test", background)
cv2.imwrite("background.jpg", background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

that generates grid like this one:

[image]

So `cv2.imshow` shows the grid but `cv2.imwrite` writes only initial black background not the grid for some reason. How to fix that?

Comment: I have a strange suspicion, could you move `cv2.waitKey(0)` one line up? so between the `imshow` and `imwrite`? and also make sure that the file you check is really the file you saved (check if the timestamp on the file is changed)

Comment: @Nullman it's change nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why my imshow differs from imwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738449/why-my-imshow-differs-from-imwrite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scale the color channels:

<s>`cv2.imwrite("background.jpg", background)`</s>

```py
cv2.imwrite("background.jpg", background * 255)
```

Alternatively you can create a "white" image with type `uint8`:

<s>`img = numpy.ones((255, 465, 3))`</s>

```py
img = numpy.ones((255, 465, 3), dtype = numpy.uint8) * 255
```